# How do I get a randomly selected hash key in Perl 6?

Tags: random, hash, key, raku, rakudo

A quick and hopefully easy question:

I need the means to select from among a given set of hash keys at random.  The perl6.org documentation on neither [**rand**](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/rand) nor [**Hash**](http://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash) offer many hints.

```
my %a = 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

Given the above,

```
%a.keys;
```

returns `(5 1 3)` and if I simply try

```
%a.rand;
```

I get a pseudorandom float rather than any one key.

I eventually cobbled together `%a.keys[Int(%a.elems.rand)]`, but was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: I eventually cobbled together

`%a.keys[Int(%a.elems.rand)]`

But was sorta hoping for simpler, I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`pick`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/pick) or [`roll`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/roll), eg

```
%a.keys.pick
```

Comment: One note on something that tripped me up with pick(): if you want to pick multiple elements from a list, non-repeating, call pick once with the number you want.  Each time you call it, it starts over with the full list and could repeat elements again.  In other words, to draw 5 cards from a deck, do this: my @hand = @deck.pick(5);    Not:  my $card1 = @deck.pick; my $card2 = @deck.pick; # etc.

Comment: or also: `%a.pick.key`

Answer (score 9):

As always, [Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097590/how-do-i-get-a-randomly-selected-hash-key-in-perl-6/35097969#35097969) is correct (he knows Perl 6 well). However, I thought I'd elaborate a little since [`pick`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/pick) and [`roll`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/roll) can easily be confused at first.

---

If you only want one random item, then [`pick`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/pick) and [`roll`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/roll) *seem* identical and can be used interchangeably because they both default to returning one item from the original list or array:

```perl6
my $rand-keyA = %a.keys.pick;

my $rand-keyB = %a.keys.roll;
```

---

However, think of them this way:
[`pick`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/pick) means "Since there are only *N* things in this container, I can only *pick* up to *N* things at once."
[`roll`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/roll) means "I have an *N*-sided dice that I can *roll* as many times as I want."

```perl6
my %a = 1,2,3,4,5,6;  # { 1 => 2, 3 => 4, 5 => 6 }
                      # (i.e. keys are 1, 3, and 5)

say %a.keys.pick(2);  # (5 3)
say %a.keys.pick(2);  # (3 1)
say %a.keys.pick(5);  # (3 5 1) no more, because there were only three to pick from
say %a.keys.pick(10); # (3 1 5) 

say %a.keys.roll(5);  # (1 5 1 5 3)           as many "rolls" as you request
say %a.keys.roll(10); # (5 5 1 1 5 5 3 1 3 1)
```

---

[`pick(*)`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/pick) is an easy way to create *a randomly reordered list* from an array without having to know how many elements it has:

```perl6
my @array = <foo bar baz foobar>;

@array.pick(*); # (bar foobar baz foo)
```

---

[`roll(*)`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/roll) is an easy way to create *an infinite list* whose elements are chosen randomly from the original array:

```perl6
my @rolls = @array.roll(*);

say @rolls[0];         # foobar
say @rolls[10];        # bar
say @rolls[351];       # baz
say @rolls[19123];     # foobar
say @rolls[1000000];   # bar
say @rolls[1000001];   # bar
say @rolls[1000002];   # foo
```

Comment: Good stuff; I appreciate the elaboration